# Trouble drawing boxes with centered letter inside

Tags: tables, boxes, letters

Basically I wanted to execute the following in latex: (Colors don't matter)

[image]

But I am having trouble doing so, because I have 0 experience with boxes. I know about arrays, but I really dont know how to execute this one. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a version using a tikz matrix:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\newlength{\myboxlength}
\begin{document}

\setlength{\myboxlength}{1cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \matrix(table)[
  matrix of nodes,
  row sep = 0.2\myboxlength,
  column sep = 0.2\myboxlength,
  nodes={ fill=none, draw=black},
  column 1/.style={minimum width=5\myboxlength},
  column 2/.style={minimum width=1\myboxlength},
  row 1/.style={minimum height=3\myboxlength},
  row 2/.style={minimum height=1\myboxlength},
  ] 
  {A & B  \\
   C & 0  \\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\bigskip

\setlength{\myboxlength}{5mm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \matrix(table)[
  matrix of nodes,
  row sep = 0.2\myboxlength,
  column sep = 0.2\myboxlength,
  nodes={ fill=none, draw=black},
  column 1/.style={minimum width=5\myboxlength},
  column 2/.style={minimum width=1\myboxlength},
  row 1/.style={minimum height=3\myboxlength},
  row 2/.style={minimum height=1\myboxlength},
  ] 
  {A & B  \\
   C & 0  \\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

```tex
\def\mybox#1#2#3{\vrule height#2\vbox to#2{\dimen0=#1\advance\dimen0by-.8pt
 \hrule width\dimen0\vfil\hbox to\dimen0{\strut\hfil#3\hfil}\vfil\hrule width\dimen0}\vrule height#2\relax}
\def\mykern{\kern1pt}
\vbox{\hbox{\mybox{5pc}{3pc}{A}\mykern\mybox{1pc}{3pc}{b}}
      \mykern
      \hbox{\mybox{5pc}{1pc}{c}\mykern\mybox{1pc}{1pc}{0}}}
```

[image]